# What is a good plain text configuration file format shared by PHP and Perl?

Tags: php, perl, configuration, configuration-files

This is more of a concept question rather than a coding problem to be solved. 
We have a number of scripts in both PHP and Perl.

There are a large number of MySQL servers spread around the company each with a large subset of different user/permission combos.

I would like to create a central configuration file, maybe as plain text file, that has a list of all the connection data. Each language would need to be able to read the files and parse them into a usable format.

I would like to know any preferred method of implementing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick any of [`ini`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), [`xml`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [`yaml`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) or [`json`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). There are libraries for working with any of these formats in Perl and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP you have [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) and for Perl you have [Config::INI::Reader](http://p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aINI%3a%3aReader). Both of these should do you pretty fine and allow structured configuration that's easily editable by humans.